# How does logging.exception gets hold of the exception?

Tags: python

Given the following code, could some python experts tell me how does `logging.exception` gets reference to the exception to print it out?

```
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except:
...     logging.exception("message")
... 
ERROR:root:message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I am assuming it's going through the traceback to get that exception message, but would be good to hear from the experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logging module got the exception via `sys.exc_info()`. You could take a look at the source code in [logging module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1439)